# Comma separated string to parent child relationship array php

Tags: php

I have a comma separated string like

```
$str = "word1,word2,word3";
```

And i want to make a parent child relationship array from it.
Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Can you at least draw the `Array` you want to achieve?

Comment: sports[0]=>
                cricket[0]=>
                                   hockey[0]=>
                                                  football[0]=>
                                                                      tennis

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357558/php-set-value-of-nested-array-using-variable-as-key

Answer (score 2):

Try this simply making own function as

```
$str = "word1,word2,word3";
$res = [];

function makeNested($arr) {
    if(count($arr)<2)
        return $arr;
    $key = array_shift($arr);
    return array($key => makeNested($arr));
}

print_r(makeNested(explode(',', $str)));
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/426674)

Answer (score 0):

```
function tooLazyToCode($string)
{
    $structure = null;
    foreach (array_reverse(explode(',', $string)) as $part) {
        $structure = ($structure == null) ? $part : array($part => $structure);
    }

    return $structure;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code it will take half of the time of the above answers:

```
<?php
$str = "sports,cricket,football,hockey,tennis";
$arr = explode(',', $str);
$result = array();
$arr_len = count($arr) - 1;
$prev = $arr_len;
for($i = $arr_len; $i>=0;$i--){
    if($prev != $i){
        $result = array($arr[$i] => $result);
    } else {
        $result = array ($arr[$i]);
    }
    $prev = $i;
}
echo '<pre>',print_r($result),'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another code for you, it will give you result as you have asked :

```
<?php
$str = "sports,cricket,football,hockey,tennis";
$arr = explode(',', $str);
$result = array();
$arr_len = count($arr) - 1;
$prev = $arr_len;
for($i = $arr_len; $i>=0;$i--){
    if($prev != $i){
        if($i == 0){
            $result = array($arr[$i] => $result);
        }else{
            $result = array(array($arr[$i] => $result));
        }

    } else {
        $result = array ($arr[$i]);
    }
    $prev = $i;
}
echo '<pre>',print_r($result),'</pre>';
```