# Create nested array by array of keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've some difficulties creating a nested array by array of keys and assigning a value for the last nested item.

For example, lets `$value = 4;` and `$keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];`

The final result should be:

```
[
  'a' => [
    'b' => [
      'c' => 4
    ]
  ]
]
```

I've tried with a recursion, but without success.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, the other question you mention as duplicate is the exact complementer of this question. Here he asked how to create the nested array from a different input format, there the nested array is given as input.

Comment: Dupe has been edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you don't need recursion, just do it from the right to left:

```
$a = $value;
for ($i = count($keys)-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
  $a = array($keys[$i] => $a);
}
```

or the even shorter version from @felipsmartins:

```
$a = $value;
foreach (array_reverse($keys) as $valueAsKey) $a = [$valueAsKey => $a];
```

Comment: This output Array
(
    [b] => Array
        (
            [c] => 4
        )

)

Comment: Pretty good! But it could be somewhat more "*easy to catch*" like this: [gist snippet](https://gist.github.com/felipsmartins/b8a5a8f7a8547506c5a7)

Comment: What you mean by "easy to catch"? (you meant "easier to understand"?) – imho just renaming  `$a` to `$new` doesn't improve much ("new" what?). Also you could as well have edited Gabriel's answer, so everybody would benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

Your can try it.

```
$value = 4;
$keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$a = $value;
$i=count($keys)-1;
foreach($keys as $key){
    $a = array($keys[$i] => $a);
    $i--;
}
print_r($a);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => 4
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution by getting a nested item in the resulting array by reference:

```php
$value = 4;
$keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$result = [];

$reference = &$result;
foreach($keys as $key) {
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $reference)) $reference[$key] = [];
    $reference = &$reference[$key];
}
$reference = $value;

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Bears a striking resemblance to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31357715/2943403)