# how to create php keys from an arrays values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like so:

```
$input = array("visit", "outdoor", "parks-trailer");
$input_content = "A Value for last array element for input array."

$another_input = array("visit", "outdoor");
$another_input_content = "A Value for last array element for $input_content array."
```

And I have some text to assign to the last element of the array, once built.

Basically, what I need is the returned array to be like this:

```
$output = array(
    "visit" => array(
        "outdoor" => array(
            "A Value for last array element for $input_content array."
            "parks-trailer" => "A Value for last array element for input array."
        )
    )
);
```

How can I do this from values of an $input array that will always be 1 dimensional.

```
$content = 'My Value';
$output = array();
$flipped = array_flip($input);
$count = count($input) - 1;

foreach($flipped as $key => $flip)
{
    if ($count >= $key)
        $output[$key] = $content;
    else
        $output[$key] = array();
}
```

The problem here is that array_flip does work, but it doesn't do multidimensional here?  And so array_flip transforms to `array('visit' => 0, 'outdoor' => 1, 'parks-trailer' => 2)`, but I'm at a loss on how to get it to do multidimensional array, not singular.

**I need to loop through multiples of these and somehow merge them into a global array, the answer given in here is not the same.**

So, I need to merge each 1 of these into another array, keeping the values, if they exist.  `array_merge` does not keep the values, `array_merge_recursive` does not keep the same key structure.  How to do this?

Comment: Will the input array always be 1-dimensional?

Comment: No, it can be different values from the array

Comment: How do you mean? Will the array you wish to use always be one-dimensional?

Comment: Ohh, yeah, it will always be 1 dimensional.  Sorry bout that.

Comment: Okay, what have you already tried?

Comment: I have tried a ton of failed attempts...  I will put them in this questions... embarrassed...

Comment: Isn't there a php function to do this?

Comment: @AbraCadaver, this question is not about setters/getters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886008/create-nested-array-by-array-of-keys

Comment: Please see edited answer...  I need values to be maintained in a global array, as I loop through all arrays and set the value to the last element of the array and merge it into a global array.

Comment: Basically, I would need to have "content" key to indicate that there is content in the array preferrably.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure sure why you would want such thing, but this is an option:

```
$ar = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function arrayMagicFunction($ar, $last_string = 'STRING') {
    $ret = $last_string;
    $ar = array_reverse($ar);
    foreach ($ar as $v) {
        $ret = [$v => $ret];
    }
    return $ret;
}
var_dump(arrayMagicFunction($ar, 'A Value here'));
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  'a' =>
  array(1) {
    'b' =>
    array(1) {
      'c' =>
      string(12) "A Value here"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @AbraCadaver, the downvote is because I didn't search for a duplicate question before answering? Just wanted to make sure... because I'm 100% sure the answer is correct.

Comment: Just so you can see that the downvote was not mine, I just downvoted.

Comment: and the reason is?

Comment: For calling me out when you have no idea who downvoted you.  But I might upvote in a minute ;-)

Comment: You are right :) sorry for that. Thought you might know know the reason here...

Comment: Please see updated question, and thanks for your help :)