# Converting php code to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

How can I convert this PHP code to JavaScript code? I am not sure about `array()` method and `=>` symbol.

Here is the code:

```
$a = $value;
for ($i = count($keys)-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
  $a = array($keys[$i] => $a);
}
```

[Create nested array by array of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886008/create-nested-array-by-array-of-keys). This is the question I am looking to get it done in java script. I have been trying so many ways but got no success.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far and can you provide a visual of `$value` and other relevant variables, also give the expected output.

Comment: Do you understand what the code does? Now reimplement it.

Comment: JavaScript has separate types for collections with named keys (`Object`) and those with sequential indexes (`Array`), whereas PHP combines both styles into `array()`s. – Related: [Best way to store a key=>value array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144705/best-way-to-store-a-key-value-array-in-javascript) and [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: Your code in PHP doesn't even make sense since you're overwriting `$a` on every iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: @Mike It embeds the previous `$a` (value or array) into the next, appearing to build a set of arrays from the inside out – `array(key0 => array(key1 => array(key2 => $value)))`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Ah, I missed the `$a` at the end. You're absolutely right.

Comment: Use `json_encode()` & `json_decode()` for php & `JSON.parse` & `JSON.stringify` in JS. JS doesn't have associative arrays, but you can use Objects as those.

Comment: Babel has supported https://babeljs.io/php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a little odd because PHP arrays are more like objects in Javascript then actual arrays. The biggest difference is syntactic:

Here is a solution that matches the provided example:

```
let a = 4
let keys = ["a", "b", "c"]

// Same as the PHP code, loop backwards
for(let i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  let key = keys[i]

  // Create a new object with the key and the old a as the value.
  a = { [key]: a }
}
```

A more functional approach would be to use `Array#reduce`:

```
let a = 4
let keys = ["a", "b", "c"]

let result = keys
  .reverse()
  .reduce((value, key) => ({ [key]: value }), a)
```

EDIT

A slightly better approach is to use `Array#reduceRight`. This will let you just have the final value you in the array:

```
let keys = ["a", "b", "c", 4]

let result = keys.reduceRight((v, k) => ({ [k]: v }))
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your response. I tried today also. I was trying like for(int i=0;i<a.length; i++) { tmp[a[i] = {}; tmp = tmp[a[i]] } . It didnt work. and finally used reduce method. But the answer by ncphillps is much shorter and precise. Thank you so much for your help.